# avax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have my service defined like;

```
@Inject
    private Crud<T> crud;


    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
    public Crud<T> crud() {
        return crud;
    }
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
        public T findById(Serializable id) {
            return crud().get(id);
        }

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public Site findById(String id) {
List<Site> results = crud().eq("id", id).list();
if (results.isEmpty()) {
throw new NoResultException();
} else {
    return results.get(0);
    }
 }
```

When I invoke my service;
I get following error. Why do I get this error?

```
        10/24/2016 2:01:21 PMCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.leightonobrien.core.model.wetstock.Site#206]
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:320)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:241)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4004)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2753)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2727)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1049)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.cdi.crud.infra.Crud.get(Crud.java:507)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.cdi.crud.infra.CrudService.findById(CrudService.java:106)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   ... 178 more
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PMCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: IJ031050: The result set is closed
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkState(WrappedResultSet.java:6004)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.wasNull(WrappedResultSet.java:4411)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:49)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:258)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:244)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:327)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2775)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:305)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   ... 227 more
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM[0m[31m03:01:21,562 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SiteEndpoint for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.leightonobrien.lob2.rest.autogen.SiteEndpoint.findById(java.lang.Long,javax.ws.rs.core.Request): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.leightonobrien.core.model.wetstock.Site#206]
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:159)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.supports(CMTTxInterceptor.java:376)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:243)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.leightonobrien.lob2.service.autogen.SiteService$$$view99.findById(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.leightonobrien.lob2.service.autogen.SiteService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findById(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.leightonobrien.lob2.rest.autogen.SiteEndpoint.findById(SiteEndpoint.java:221)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor306.invoke(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:110)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.leightonobrien.lob2.rest.autogen.SiteEndpoint$$$view118.findById(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor306.invoke(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:433)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:128)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.leightonobrien.lob2.rest.autogen.SiteEndpoint$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findById(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor340.invoke(Unknown Source)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at com.cdi.crud.infra.filter.ApplicationFilter.doFilter(ApplicationFilter.java:54)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.handleRequest(UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:66)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    10/24/2016 2:01:21 PM   at 
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM[0m[31m03:01:20,722 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-40) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component SiteEndpoint for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.leightonobrien.lob2.rest.autogen.SiteEndpoint.findById(java.lang.Long,javax.ws.rs.core.Request): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000151: Some connections were not closed, see the log for the allocation stacktraces
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM   at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
10/24/2016 2:01:20 PM   at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
```

Comment: please share full stack trace

Comment: @DarkKnight provided more error stack

Comment: what is crud()? a method or a class instance.  share code of crud